# Which AWS service would be more ideal for hosting a GO program when called from Telegram webooks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, telegram-bot

I have a specific question regarding AWS services in that I have an application written in GO sitting in a EC2 instance.  I also have created a bot in Telegram which uses webhooks to make function calls back to the program.  The program requires a login as there are multiple people that use this and I was wondering if there was a better way to host this type of program whether it be AWS Lambda, Elastic Beanstock etc.  I want each user to have their own instance but still using the same database.

Comment: What do you mean by ` I want each user to have their own instance`? What instance, like in EC2 instance?

Comment: When you say "the program requires a login", how does this login work if connected via Telegram? Does authentication information get passed through the webhook?

Comment: When I say instance - I mean they will login to the application and have their own environment, data and settings

Comment: The telegram bot uses an api call to a function in the program that then calls another function using Google Firebase.  The program then relays the login prompt back to the telgram bot